# How to turn html tags into an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am relatively new to JavaScript but I have a lot of background in java. So, I am wondering how I could loop through every single tag in a special div. Like a for loop. This is what I have already:

```
var allPeople = document.getElementsByClassName('person').toArray;

console.log(allPeople.length);

for(var i = 0; i < allPeople.length; i++) {
    console.log(document.getElementById("#main > .person > #inside > #span"));
    document.getElementById("#main > .person > #inside > #left > li > #normal > #kd").innerHTML = 1;
}
```

I think the problem is with the 'document.getElementsByClassName('person').toArray;' part. Any other recommendations?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('person')` that returns an iterable array like result. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Your getElementById looks a bit quirky as well, make `document.querySelectorAll("#main > .person > #inside > #span")` which in turn would return an array

Comment: `var allPeople = Array.apply(null, document.getElementsByClassName('person'));`

Comment: unrelated, why you have ` #main > .person > #inside > #span` with `getElementById` ?

Comment: `var allPeople = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('person');`

Answer (score 0):

remove the `.toArray` in line 1

the function `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array, you do not need to convert it to one.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` doesn't return an array, but rather a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) which doesn't have the Array methods. But you can still iterate it with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using es6

`[ ...document.getElementsByClassName('person')].forEach( el => { //do something })`